# How to create smart playlists on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have a problem: each time I create an album in a smartplaylist in iTunes and sync it with my iPhone, I have multiple items of the same album with different artists names.
I'm wondering how to create smartplaylists so that I can unify my albums.
Have you heard of [Smartplaylists](http://www.appshouter.com/smartplaylist-iphone-app-review/)? Which app would you suggest me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have on your library same album and different artists or, most likely, you're creating some weird rules that generate that behavior, like [other folks did](http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2576954&tstart=0). If that's the case, seems like you'd have to change `+` to `...` in any rule that uses the plus sign. Granted, it is inconsistent behavior in this second case and it might get fixed in the future. And, who knows, there might be few other little bugs like this as well.

Answer (score 0):

[SmartPlaylist](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smartplaylist/id326071802?mt=8) $1.99 in the App Store. Amazing app. It lets you sort by many many different parameters (artist, song length, genre, plays, etc.). I highly highly recommend this app. It is a but counterintuitive at first, but stick with it, and you won't regret the $2 you paid for it.